# Optional Command line parameter Shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell

lets call the following replace.sh

```
if "$1" !=""
then
  REPLACE_AS=$1
else
  REPLACE_AS="Tebow"
fi
find . ! -regex ".*[/]\.svn[/]?.*" -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -n 1 sed -i -e 's/SANCHEZ/'$REPLACE_AS'/g'
```

Sorry for the primitive question. I am trying to make it so the command line parameter is optional . IE if someone doesn't put it and just runs this script it uses Tebow. That seems to work. However if i run the script with a command line argument it doesnt work.

ie

./test.sh

this will replace it with tebow.

however 
./test.sh Smith

will not replace the Sanchez string with Smith

Comment: http://www.shelldorado.com/goodcoding/cmdargs.html   looking at this now

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [shell parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) and the notation:

```
REPLACE_AS="${1:-Tebow}"
```

to do in one line what you do in 6.

Additionally, your code as written should be:

```
if [ "$1" != "" ]
then REPLACE_AS="$1"
else REPLACE_AS="Tebow"
fi
```

The test command is `[`; it needs spaces around its operands and a `]` at the end.  You need quotes around `"$1"` in case it contains spaces; the quotes around `"Tebow"` are optional because it doesn't contain spaces (but the uniformity is good).

There's nothing to stop you writing:

```
xargs -0 -n 1 sed -i -e 's/SANCHEZ/'"${1:-Tebow}"'/g'
```

but the clarity of the variable is good, especially if you'll refer to it several times.

Also, I would leave the pipe at the end of the line and start the second command (`xargs`) on the second line for clarity (again - it is very important).

```
find . ! -regex ".*[/]\.svn[/]?.*" -type f -print0 |
xargs -0 -n 1 sed -i -e 's/SANCHEZ/'"$REPLACE_AS"'/g'
```

Sometimes, but not often, I'll indent the second command.
Note the double quotes around `"$REPLACE_AS"`; it prevents problems with spaces in the replacement text.